# Update svn checkout to specific date including externals

Tags: svn, history, svn-externals

I want to perform an svn update to a specific date, and I can do this with `svn update -r {2010-10-17}`.  Unfortunately when this encounters an external it will do the update within the external without passing through the `-r {2010-10-17}` option.  This results in us getting the correct past revision of the base code, but the latest (undesired) versions of many of the externals.

How can I update to a specific revision or date and have this recurse correctly through the externals?

(Note: I understand that the mistake here might have been to use externals with no explicit revisions specified.)

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683716/subversion-update-externals-to-a-date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope, anybody will implement my common-sense logic (limited to directory-type externals in some areas) into bash and cmd-script sooner or later and we'll get *"definitive answer"* to this repeating question

Your base task is:

- `svn up` your super-repo to needed point in past (updating to date /and without time/ is, BTW, not a best choice, but - apllicable)
- get list of paths to all externals in your project (because externals definitions can exist anywhere in tree), from WC-root `svn propget svn:externals -R` (-R in order to check the whole tree without a lot of `cd`)
- for each string in propget output (with format like this `. - https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-trouble-shooting/trunk/lib lib`): cd to the last field of string /relative to the first field, which is, in turn, is relative path to root/ and svn up to the same point, as it was done for superrepo: `svn update -r {2010-10-17}`

As result you'll have Mixed Working Copy, but superrepo and externals will be in state "for some revision in the past"

Note:

Additional sample for constructing local path to directory with externals (nested WC really) on more complex case.

For

```
>svn propget svn:externals -R
tags\1.0.1 - -r 2 https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-trouble-shooting/trunk/lib@2 lib

trunk - https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-trouble-shooting/trunk/lib lib
```

finals paths to externals in my WC will be (relative to WC-root)

```
tags\1.0.1\lib
trunk\lib
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer in case anyone's trying to **update an already-checked-out subversion repository to sync the local file dates to the repo dates**, which I wanted to do so I could do FS timestamp comparisons.

I made this oneliner to do the trick (but read the line below before using it):

`svn info --show-item last-changed-date -R | xargs -I{} -P1000 -n1 sh -c 'x="{}"; set -x; exec touch -d "${x%% *}" "${x#* }"'`

**NOTE:** The `-P1000` specifies that `xargs` should run ***1000*** simultaneous copies of `sh` and `touch` to do the actual updating. Depending on system load it may be wise to lower this. On a tiny i3-based Intel NUC 1000 processes actually turned out to be perfect, using 80-95% CPU (100% generally means the CPU is overloaded). If in doubt, open eg `htop` and test with different values - but only run it for a few seconds, because it will need to run from the start each time.

For a small ~3GB SVN repo on a USB HDD, this took about 5 minutes to run.

The `set +x` turns on verbose execution, which I do just before executing `touch` so you can watch it run. If you want non-verbose execution, remove that command.

Answer (score 0):

We include only whole dirs in other projects:

- mainprj/**bin**/subprj1
- mainprj/**bin**/subprj2
- mainprj/**dat**/subprj1
- mainprj/**dat**/subprj2
- subprj1/**bin**   # included in mainprj/**bin**/subprj1
- subprj1/**dat**   # included in mainprj/**dat**/subprj1
- subprj2/**bin**   # included in mainprj/**bin**/subprj2
- subprj2/**dat**   # included in mainprj/**dat**/subprj2

with this layout `svn propget svn:externals -R` returns

```
# cd mainprj
# svn propget svn:externals -R
bin - subprj1 svn+ssh://svnserver/svn/subprj1/trunk/bin
subprj2 svn+ssh://svnserver/svn/subprj2/trunk/bin

dat - subprj1 svn+ssh://svnserver/svn/subprj1/trunk/dat
subprj2 svn+ssh://svnserver/svn/subprj2/trunk/dat
```

and you can update to a fix date as follows:

```
svn propget svn:externals -R |\ 
   grep -vE '^$' | sed -e "s/^[^-]* - //" |\
   while read line; do \
      pushd ${line##*/}; \
         svn update -r {2019-04-26} ${line%% *}; \
      popd; \
   done
```

Answer (score -3):

As far as I've been able to work out, you can't do this without changing your externals config.  But, changing the externals config changes it for everyone, so it's just a single commit and update and you're done.

Comment: Can you explain what an "externals config" is?  Do you mean the svn:externals property?

If you mean that our externals properties should all use explicit revision numbers, then yes I might agree with you, but I can't go back and edit the many commits for which this wasn't the case.

Perhaps I misunderstand your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, the svn:externals property.  You only have that in one or two places right?  Although, now rereading your question, you want to be going back in time, which will reset the svn:externals property too.  So yes, you should have used explicit revisions on your externals, and now you're going to have to do it manually :)